# PHP 8.0 - Apache - phpMyAdmin - Docker Image

Tags: php, mysql, docker, apache, pdo

I am creating an image for a php8 project run on apache, and work with phpMyAdmin, I have my Dockerfile as follow :

```
FROM php:8.0-apache
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y libmariadb-dev && docker-php-ext-install mysqli && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
WORKDIR /var/www/html
```

And my docker-compose.yml as follow :

```
services:
  php-apache-environment:
    container_name: php-apache
    image: php:8.0-apache
    volumes:
      - ./php/src:/var/www/html/
    ports:
      - 8000:80

  db:
    container_name: db
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
      MYSQL_DATABASE: MY_DATABASE
      MYSQL_USER: MYSQL_USER
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: MYSQL_PASSWORD
    ports:
      - "9906:3306"
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin:latest
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    restart: always
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
    depends_on:
      - db
```

For me, all is good, but when I run "docker compose up --build", container is launched, but he has not install "mysqli" and "pdo_mysql" like I request in the Dockerfile.

But, if I log in by CLI to the PHP container, and that I run `docker-php-ext-install mysqli` and `docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql`, it works, and I just have to restart the PHP container.

But, I dont know why, I can't install it from the start ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: because you are using: image: php:8.0-apache you should use build instead. this could be useful: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/build/#build-definition

Answer (score 1):

Thans to Lety comment, we juste need to change the line 4 of docker-compose.yml
by :

```
build: ./php
```

(to indicate the directory where the Dockerfile is) and it works.

Resume :
Dont change the Dockerfile
. Change the docker-compose.yml by :

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  php-apache-environment:
    container_name: php-apache
    build: ./php
    volumes:
      - ./php/src:/var/www/html/
    ports:
      - 8000:80

  db:
    container_name: db
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
      MYSQL_DATABASE: MY_DATABASE
      MYSQL_USER: MYSQL_USER
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: MYSQL_PASSWORD
    ports:
      - "9906:3306"
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin:latest
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    restart: always
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
    depends_on:
      - db
```